# Unable to build ES6 version of my React App with webpack and babel-preset-env

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I decided to rewrite my existing React App from ES5 to ES6. Below is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ToDoList from './to-do-list.jsx';

//Put the components into HTML
ReactDOM.render(<ToDoList/>, document.getElementById('todo-wrapper'));
```

However when I try to build with webpack and launch the app I get the error that:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/index.js
Module parse failed: /home/sam/devzone/github/simple-react-todo-app/src/app/index.js Unexpected token (6:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| //Put the components into HTML
| ReactDOM.render(<ToDoList/>, document.getElementById('todo-wrapper'));
```

I have selected `babel-preset-env` instead of `babel-preset-es2015`, but I highly doubt that this is the cause. Below are snapshots of my `package.json` and my `webpack.config.js` respectively.

**package.json**

```
"main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --port 1234"
  },
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "eslint": "^4.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/app/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') + '/app',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/app/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                        "presets": [
                            ["env", {
                                "loose": true,
                                "modules": false,
                                "useBuiltIns": true,
                                "debug": true,
                                "include": ["transform-es2015-classes"]
                            }],
                            "react"
                        ],
                        "plugins": [
                            "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters",
                            "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring"
                        ]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ],
        rules: [
            {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

As it might be evident that I did a bit trial and error myself, but I seem to be totally lost now.

The app folder structure and other relevant files can be seen inside my repo [here](https://github.com/mobbarley/simple-react-todo-app/tree/initial).

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently it seems to be, but my searches did not point me to this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webpack's config is wrong (it's old config from Webpack 1)

You should change it to:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/app/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') + '/app',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/app/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
             {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                        "presets": [
                            ["env", {
                                "loose": true,
                                "modules": false,
                                "useBuiltIns": true,
                                "debug": true,
                                "include": ["transform-es2015-classes"]
                            }],
                            "react"
                        ],
                        "plugins": [
                            "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters",
                            "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring"
                        ]
                }
            },
            {
              test: /\.css$/,
              use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
test: /\.jsx?$/,
```

To

```
test: /.(js|jsx)?$/,
```